# make radio button checked if it has the right database value

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and HTML, I have a function that is on a different class for where I fetch the database value and make the radio button set to selected if it contains the value.

```
    public function getstatusradio () {
    $sql = "SELECT ticketstatus FROM ticketpractice WHERE id = 6";
    $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
    if ($result-> rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch()){
               echo "<input type='radio' name='status' <?php if($row['ticketstatus']=='new') {echo 'checked';} ?> value='new '>new";
               echo "<input type='radio' name='status' <?php if($row['ticketstatus']=='processing') {echo 'checked';} ?> value='processing'>processing";
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is as I declare the code inside my HTML page

```
<div>
<?php
  $object = new myclass;
  $object->getstatusradio();
?>
</div>
```

this is the result that I want to achieve where the correct radio button is selected according to the database values "new" and "processing." in this example the database value is "processing.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkP6N.png)"

As of now this the result I have

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or
>   number (T_NUM_STRING)"

Comment: I assume that php code is in `<?php ?>` so why you writting again `<?php ?>` in echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code to below:

```
 public function getstatusradio () {
    $sql = "SELECT ticketstatus FROM ticketpractice WHERE id = 6";
    $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
    if ($result-> rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch()){
               $newCheck = $row['ticketstatus']=='new' ? 'checked' : '';
               $processingCheck = $row['ticketstatus']=='processing' ? 'checked' : '';
               echo "<input type='radio' name='status' $newCheck value='new '>new";
               echo "<input type='radio' name='status' $processingCheck value='processing'>processing";
            }
        }
    }
```

but if you want to use php tag inside "", use [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
$phpCode = '<? if($condtion){ ?>';
echo htmlspecialchars($phpCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrong here :

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='status' <?php if($row['ticketstatus']=='new') {echo 'checked';} ?> value='new '>new";
echo "<input type='radio' name='status' <?php if($row['ticketstatus']=='processing') {echo 'checked';} ?> value='processing'>processing";
```

You don't need do open again `<?php` for use if, because you are already on php tag

So the code will be:

```
if($row['ticketstatus']=='new'{
echo "<input type='radio' name='status' value='new ' checked>";
}elseif($row['ticketstatus']=='processing'{
echo "<input type='radio' name='status' value='processing' checked>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `<?php ?>` tags again inside a php code.
You also don't need to do `echo` again inside one `echo`.

The example below can be simpler, but I want you to understand what is going on.

```
<?php
    public function getstatusradio () {
    $sql = "SELECT ticketstatus FROM ticketpractice WHERE id = 6";
    $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
        if ($result-> rowCount() > 0) {
            $output1="";
            $output2="";
            while ($row = $result->fetch()){
               $output1 .= "<input type='radio' name='status'";
               $output1 .= $row['ticketstatus']=='new'?'checked':"";
               $output1 .= " value='new '>new";
               $output2 .= "<input type='radio' name='status'";
               $output2 .= $row['ticketstatus']=='processing'?'checked':"";
               $output2 .= " value='processing'>processing";
            }
            // do whatever you like to the output. You may return it or `echo` it later or ...
            echo $output1;
            echo $output2;
        }
    }
?>
```